# SQLAlchemy AmbiguousForeignKeysError

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

i have searched for this error and couldn't understand nothing. I am getting the error below:

> sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on relationship Sale.payments - there are multiple foreign key paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the parent table.

Here is my code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlalchemy as sa
import bcrypt as bc
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker, relationship, backref
from sqlalchemy_utils import database_exists, create_database

engine = sa.create_engine('sqlite:///data/db/nestopol.db')
if not database_exists(engine.url):
    create_database(engine.url)

session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()


class Staff(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'staffs'

    staff_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = sa.Column(sa.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)

    # Needs a length if MySQL is used
    # password is 93 in length
    password = sa.Column(sa.String(124), nullable=False)
    admin = sa.Column(sa.Boolean, default=False, nullable=False)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    gender = sa.Column(sa.String(6), nullable=False)
    birthday = sa.Column(sa.String(11), nullable=False)
    mobile_number = sa.Column(sa.String(14), nullable=False)
    city = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    state = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    country = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    address = sa.Column(sa.String(128), nullable=False)
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    modified_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    customers = relationship('Customer', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    products = relationship('Product', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    categories = relationship('Category', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    suppliers = relationship('Supplier', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    supply = relationship('Supply', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    sales = relationship('Sale', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    items = relationship('Item', backref='staffs', lazy='select')
    payments = relationship('Payment', backref='staffs', lazy='select')

    def generate_password_hash(self, password):
        return bc.hashpw(self.password, bc.gensalt())

    def check_password_hash(self, plain_text_password, password):
        return bc.checkpw(plain_text_password, self.hashed_password)


class Customer(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'customers'

    customer_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    first_name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    last_name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    email = sa.Column(sa.String(64), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    gender = sa.Column(sa.String(7), nullable=False)
    birthday = sa.Column(sa.String(11), nullable=False)
    phone = sa.Column(sa.String(14), nullable=False)
    city = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    state = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    country = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    address = sa.Column(sa.String(128), nullable=False)
    description = sa.Column(sa.String(128), nullable=False)
    purchases = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    expenditure = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    reward = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    modified_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    sales = relationship('Sale', backref='customers', lazy='select')
    items = relationship('Item', backref='customers', lazy='select')
    payments = relationship('Payment', backref='customers', lazy='select')



class Product(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'products'

    product_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = sa.Column(sa.String(128), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    category = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('categories.product_category_id'))
    cost_price = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    selling_price = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    weight = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    stock = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    discount = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    expires = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    supplier = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('suppliers.supplier_id'))
    description = sa.Column(sa.String(128), nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    items = relationship('Item', backref='products', lazy='select')


class Category(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'categories'

    product_category_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    products = relationship('Product', backref='categories', lazy='select')


class Supplier(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'suppliers'

    supplier_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    debt = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    email = sa.Column(sa.String(64), unique = True, index=True, nullable=False)
    phone = sa.Column(sa.String(14), nullable=False)
    city = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    state = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    country = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    address = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    description = sa.Column(sa.String(200), nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    modified_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    products = relationship('Product', backref='suppliers', lazy='select')
    supplies = relationship('Supply', backref='suppliers', lazy='select')


class Supply(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'supplies'

    supply_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    title = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    supplier = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('suppliers.supplier_id'))
    items = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    value = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)

class Sale(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'sales'

    sale_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    code = sa.Column(sa.String(8), unique=True, index=True, nullable=False)
    title = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    customer = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('customers.customer_id'))
    total = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    discount = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    vat = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    payment_method = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    payment = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('payments.payment_id'))
    state = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    item = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('items.item_id'))
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    payments = relationship('Payment', backref='sales', lazy='select')
    items = relationship('Item', backref='sales', lazy='select')

class Item(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'items'

    item_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    customer = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('customers.customer_id'))
    item = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('products.product_id'))
    quantity = sa.Column(sa.Integer, nullable=False)
    total = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    sales = relationship('Sale', backref='items', lazy='select')


class Payment(Base):

    __tablename__ = 'payments'

    payment_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    customer = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('customers.customer_id'))
    status = sa.Column(sa.String(26), nullable=False)
    amount_paid = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    amount_due = sa.Column(sa.Float, nullable=False)
    comment = sa.Column(sa.String(128), nullable=False)
    author = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('staffs.staff_id'))
    added_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    modified_on = sa.Column(sa.DateTime)
    sales = relationship('Sale', backref='payments', lazy='select')



Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Please how do i fix this

Answer (score 9):

The following code reproduces the issue (also note that where you've used `backref`, I've modified to `back_populates`, you'll need to explore the difference between the two):

```
class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'
    sale_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    payment = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('payments.payment_id'))
    payments = relationship('Payment', back_populates='sales', lazy='select')

class Payment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'payments'
    payment_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    sales = relationship('Sale', back_populates='payments', lazy='select')

Sale()
```

When I run that code I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.AmbiguousForeignKeysError: Could not determine join condition between
parent/child tables on relationship Sale.payments - there are multiple foreign key 
paths linking the tables.  Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of 
those columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference to the 
parent table.
```

Lets break the exception message down:

> Could not determine join condition between parent/child tables on
> relationship Sale.payments - there are multiple foreign key paths
> linking the tables.

This is telling you what is wrong. Sqlalchemy doesn't know how to create the relationship `Sale.payments`. This is because, if no explicit join condition is provided, sqlalchemy looks to the Foreign Key's between the tables for guidance. In this case there are two foreign keys linking the tables, `Sale.payment` is a FK of `Payment.payment_id` and `Payment.sale` is a FK to `Sale.sale_id`. This is why the join condition is "ambiguous" - because there are two potential join path's between the two tables.

> Specify the 'foreign_keys' argument, providing a list of  those
> columns which should be counted as containing a foreign key reference
> to the  parent table.

This is telling you how to resolve the problem. We could do this and it will work:

```
class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'
    sale_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    payment = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('payments.payment_id'))
    payments = relationship('Payment', back_populates='sales', lazy='select',
                            foreign_keys=[payment])

class Payment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'payments'
    payment_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    sales = relationship('Sale', back_populates='payments', lazy='select',
                         foreign_keys=[Sale.payment])
```

But I think the real issue here is that the two foreign keys aren't necessary. This code achieves the exact same result without the circular FK:

```
class Sale(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'sales'
    sale_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    payments = relationship('Payment', back_populates='sales', lazy='select')

class Payment(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'payments'
    payment_id = sa.Column(sa.Integer, primary_key=True)
    sale = sa.Column(sa.Integer, sa.ForeignKey('sales.sale_id'))
    sales = relationship('Sale', back_populates='payments', lazy='select')
```

Now that the circular FK refs are gone, there is only one FK path between the two tables and sqlalchemy can easily reason out the correct join path for the relationship and we don't need to specify the `foreign_keys` parameter.